# Android Release Fail

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I'm having some troubles with an Android application. It's using React Native (version 0.72.5) and I use Android Studio to emulate it. At some point, I made some implementations 'native-base' and '@react-navigation/native' on it (in both cases, I followed the documentation), and it works perfectly on the emulator. Now, I'm trying to generate the release .apk.

I followed all the steps [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/react-native-generate-apk-debug-and-release-apk-4e9981a2ea51) and it was generated.

Then, I tried running it at my cellphone, but it's not working... nor giving me any logs to see what error is happening... and now I have no idea what to do about it.

This is the configuration I'm using, that works fine on the emulator:

My App.jsx file:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Login"
          screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen
            component={Login}
            name="Login"
            options={{headerShown: false, animationEnabled: false}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            component={BottomTabNavigator}
            name="Tabs"
            screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            component={Finish}
            name="Finish"
            options={{headerShown: false, animationEnabled: false}}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

My BottomTabNavigator.jsx file:

```
class BottomTabNavigator extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      badgeData: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCountCompleted();
  
    this.updateInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.getCountCompleted();
    }, 4000);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.updateInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.updateInterval);
    }
  }

  getCountCompletedEscalas = async () => {
    try {
      const realm = await getRealm();
      const data = realm.objects('scale').filtered('complete = ' + 1);
      const count = data.length;
  
      this.setState({ badgeData: count });
  
      storeData('@badgeData', count);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="HomeTab"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5', height: screenHeight * 0.09},
        }}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "#39B44A",
          inactiveTintColor: "#C3CDDE",
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          component={Download}
          name="DownloadTab"
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "",
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          component={Local}
          name="LocalTab"
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "",
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          component={Home}
          name="HomeTab"
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "",
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          component={Upload}
          name="UploadTab"
          options={{
            tabBarBadge: this.state.badgeData > 0 ? this.state.badgeData : null,
            tabBarLabel: "",
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          component={Help}
          name="HelpTab"
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "",
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          component={Areas}
          name="AreaTab"
          options={{
            tabBarButton: () => null,
            tabBarVisible: false
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          component={Inspect}
          name="InspectTab"
          options={{
            tabBarButton: () => null,
            tabBarVisible: false
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
}

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

Comment: In the android logs, you should be able to see fatal exception, which can tell you what it crashed. Try to run the application few times and filter logs for fatal(error).
Are you able to see the logs from Android device? You can also access logs with the following ADB command from the terminal: "adb logcat"